# How values of the constants are derived mathematically?

Tags: calculus, math-history, education, constants

As said by Jan regarding constant value  $\pi$ ,Imagine you have a circle and you are able to measure its circumference "c". Then, you can also find out what its diameter
"d" is. When you divide circumference by diameter, that is "c/d" you get a number. When you try this on various circles, and if you measure "c" and "d" more and more precisely, you will see that you get some
constant, that is called $\pi$.

Similarly there are many other extremely important constants . So can anybody tell me  how values of the constants are derived mathematically like the imaginary unit $j$, Euler value $e$, electric charge etc?

Comment: Can you name specific constants? Otherwise, this could be too broad.

Comment: I would recommend you this http://www.amazon.com/The-Constants-Nature-Numbers-Universe/dp/1400032253

Comment: Real numbers are *a lot*. The ones naturally arising in mathematics are relatively few, but they do so in many different ways. So, unless you name a specific one, this question might be too vague.

Comment: A special constant will have a **definition** of the constant.  Many of which have either a series or recursive definition (or at least canonical representation) of some sort.  E.g. $e = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$.  If you add the first, say, 50 terms of that series, you will get arbitrarily close, just like how with $\pi$ you can take more and more precise measurements (or rather use regular polygons with more and more sides to approximate the circle).

Comment: The edit is about constants in *physics*, not *mathematics*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a whole bunch of ways to determine the values of different constants. I'll tell you about some of the historic methods.

## $\pi$

One of the oldest methods used was the [exhaustion method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_exhaustion), by Archimedes. He put a circle in between two polygons of equivalent sides and gradually increased the number of sides until the two became nearly identical, leading him to determine the area of the circle.

[image]

## e

The first person to approximate this was [Jacob Bernoulli](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/HistTopics/e.html), who solved the limit of
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

Later, in his *Introductio in Analysin infinitorum*, Euler used a power series (the MacLaurin series for $e^1$) to approximate $e$:
$$e=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$$

## $\gamma$

[Euler first explored](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Euler_constant) the Euler-Mascheroni constant by investigating another limit:
$$\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(- \ln n +\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}\right)$$

$i$

The [imaginary unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit) isn't really a constant; it's the basis for a whole new system of numbers. It has no real-number value. The only way you could efficiently relate it to real numbers would be to use its definition:
$$i=\sqrt{-1}$$

---

On an interesting note, $\pi$, $e$ and $\gamma$ were all determined by limiting methods.

Comment: Also, $e^{i\pi}=-1$